DHCP does not work
I'm trying to config a notebook as router, with 3 NICs, 2 used to connect to internet (with modems with DHCP servers embeded), and 1 to connect to LAN, with a switch (I want to use an ubuntu dhcp server on this NIC).
I installed isc-dhcp-server.
Firewall is down.
Ping is working on local machine.
nslookup works on local machine.
"ip a" command shows interfaces are up.
network cable is working.
client computer works connecting directly to any of the 2 modems.
my config files:
What am I doing wrong?
/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

network:
  ethernets:
    ens2f1:
      dhcp4: true
    enx5c628b861dcb:
      dhcp4: true
    enx5c628b74c1be:
      dhcp4: false (also tried "no")
      addresses:
        - 10.0.0.1/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
  version:2

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0{
  interface enx5c628b74c1be;
  range 10.0.0.100 10.0.0.200;
  option routers 10.0.0.1;
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
}

/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server

INTERFACESv4="enx5c628b74c1be"

/etc/sysctl.conf

net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

